# Printing MySQL table rows matching variable input

Tags: php, mysql

The query in the following returns the data I want when I provide value I want to find a match for, however, I seem to be having difficulty when returning the data using the echo statements at the end:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password, $database) or die (mysql_error ());

$searched=$_POST['searched'];
$sound = soundex($searched);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM word_list WHERE sound = '$sound';";
$result = mysql_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['word'] . ':' . $row['sound'] . '<br />';
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The output in a browser is a blank page (no errors logged, etc.). When I var_dump the input, I get the correct soundex value; I am not sure where I've overlooked something, as seen above, tried a few things I saw in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800587/php-and-mysql-printing-rows-matching-a-column-value).

'string(4) "A000"' is the result of the var_dump. As I explained, when I use 'A000' in place of my $sound variable, the query is successful in MySQL, and returns a list of words with matching soundex values (stored in a column called 'sound'), but I can't seem to get it to readout as such in the browser.

Comment: coooool! in the first line you use "mysqli_connect", in 7 "mysql_query" :)

Comment: it might be because you have a mysqli connection but are using mysql_query?  try changing to mysqli for all your code.

Comment: Blargh, thank you. That was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mysqli_query instead of mysql_query. 
I think mysqli_connect returns an object and mysql_query needs a string.

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked that.

Comment: No problem :) It's always easier to see someone else's mistakes ;)